# How can I change the number of snapping points 'Slide Vertex' uses?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I would like to ask if there is any way to change the number of snapping points in 'Slide Vertex' that is enabled when holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>? I think I have seen tutorial years ago but I cannot recall it now (or maybe it was Maya).

[image].

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>G</kbd> twice to slide a vertex and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. It will allow you to snap a vertex very precisely.
[image]

Also, after pressing <kbd>G</kbd> twice, you can move a vertex inputting a value from your numerical keyboard.
[image]